# How to autofill data in a dataframe based on the date a value last changed for each group in a groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to write a script that will tell me which of my Facebook ads were live on a certain date, as I tend to pause and resume a lot. Since Facebook doesn't have a great way to check this easily, I made a function that uses the activities edge of the API and returns the activity history for a list of ads, specifically each occurrence of an ad's run status changing in a given time period.

Let's say ad A was created on 12/1, paused on 12/10 and then resumed on 12/20. Instead of giving me this (which is the output I'm trying to get for each ad):

```
12/1: ACTIVE
12/2: ACTIVE
12/3: ACTIVE
12/4: ACTIVE
12/5: ACTIVE
12/6: ACTIVE
12/7: ACTIVE
12/8: ACTIVE
12/9: ACTIVE
12/10: PAUSED
12/11: PAUSED
12/12: PAUSED
12/13: PAUSED
12/14: PAUSED
12/15: PAUSED
12/16: PAUSED
12/17: PAUSED
12/18: PAUSED
12/19: PAUSED
12/20: ACTIVE
12/21: ACTIVE
12/22: ACTIVE
12/23: ACTIVE
12/24: ACTIVE
12/25: ACTIVE
12/26: ACTIVE
12/27: ACTIVE
12/28: ACTIVE
12/29: ACTIVE
12/30: ACTIVE
12/31: ACTIVE
```

Facebook's API only returns the dates when changes actually occurred to an ad:

```
12/10: PAUSED
12/20: ACTIVE
```

So I'm trying to find a way to autofill this information in pandas. I'm pulling ad activity history starting from each individual ad's start date, and I've been using this function below to fill in the dates between an ad's start date and a specified date:

```
def fill_dates(df):
    fill_data = []
    def filler(row):
        start = row['start'].date()
        split_row = [start+timedelta(days=x) for x in range((todate(now())-start).days+1)]
        for s in split_row:
            new_row = row.to_dict()
            new_row['date'] = s
            fill_data.append(new_row)
    df.apply(filler,axis=1)
    return pd.DataFrame(fill_data)
```

> (Note: todate() and now() are my own custom functions for getting and
>   parsing dates/times, just in case anyone was wondering)

Here's some mock data of what I have now after using the above function to fill in the dates:

```
ix  ad_id        date       status
0   12345678910  2018-11-21 PAUSED
1   12345678910  2018-11-22 PAUSED
2   12345678910  2018-11-23 PAUSED
3   12345678910  2018-11-24 PAUSED
4   12345678910  2018-11-25 PAUSED
5   12345678910  2018-11-26 PAUSED
6   12345678910  2018-11-27 PAUSED
7   12345678910  2018-11-28 PAUSED
8   12345678910  2018-11-29 PAUSED
9   12345678910  2018-11-30 PAUSED
10  111213141516 2018-11-21 PAUSED
11  111213141516 2018-11-22 PAUSED
12  111213141516 2018-11-23 PAUSED
13  111213141516 2018-11-24 PAUSED
14  111213141516 2018-11-25 PAUSED
15  111213141516 2018-11-26 PAUSED
16  111213141516 2018-11-27 PAUSED
17  111213141516 2018-11-28 PAUSED
18  111213141516 2018-11-29 PAUSED
19  111213141516 2018-11-30 PAUSED
20  171819202122 2018-11-21 PAUSED
21  171819202122 2018-11-22 PAUSED
22  171819202122 2018-11-23 PAUSED
23  171819202122 2018-11-24 PAUSED
24  171819202122 2018-11-25 PAUSED
25  171819202122 2018-11-26 PAUSED
26  171819202122 2018-11-27 PAUSED
27  171819202122 2018-11-28 PAUSED
28  171819202122 2018-11-29 PAUSED
29  171819202122 2018-11-30 PAUSED
```

And here's the source data that was used to generate the above output:

```
ix  ad_id        date       status  start_date
0   12345678910  2018-12-26 PAUSED  2018-11-21
1   111213141516 2018-12-26 PAUSED  2018-11-21
2   171819202122 2018-12-26 PAUSED  2018-11-21
```

While this took care of filling in the dates, it does nothing for determining what each ad's status actually was on a particular day. I think part of the trouble here is due to the API not recording ads as active on their start date, it seems to only record run status changes *after* creation. So I figured I'd have to manually add that information, like this:

```
ix  ad_id        date       status  start_date
0   12345678910  2018-11-21 ACTIVE  2018-11-21
1   12345678910  2018-12-26 PAUSED  2018-11-21
2   111213141516 2018-11-21 ACTIVE  2018-11-21
3   111213141516 2018-12-26 PAUSED  2018-11-21
4   171819202122 2018-11-21 ACTIVE  2018-11-21
5   171819202122 2018-12-26 PAUSED  2018-11-21
```

But I don't think that will be enough to get an accurate output. I'm still not quite sure exactly what logic to apply when I group the dataframe by ad_id (assuming grouping is the way to go?) for the script to figure out what the status of each ad was on a particular day using that ad's activity history.

I hope I was clear enough, if not please let me know and I'll do my best to better articulate the issue. I'd be super grateful for any ideas/advice anyone has for tackling this!

Comment: Can you clarify?  What is your input data look like for multiple ads over 2 state changes each?

Comment: Please mention your input and expected output data clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your input data so I'm showing an example with data from my Facebook Ads account.

You can basically use the "impressions" column from Facebook Ads to create the flag that you need.

| date | ad_id | impressions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-21 | Big Donut | 4684 |
| 2022-07-22 | Big Donut | 5230 |
| 2022-07-23 | Big Donut | 0 |
| 2022-07-24 | Big Donut | 0 |

```
df['Active/Paused'] = np.where(df['impressions'] == 0, 0, 1)
```

| date | ad_id | impressions | Active/Paused |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-21 | Big Donut | 4684 | 1 |
| 2022-07-22 | Big Donut | 5230 | 1 |
| 2022-07-23 | Big Donut | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-07-24 | Big Donut | 0 | 0 |

I created a Colab notebook where you can get more details of this solution, the link is below. If you still want to work with the flag that the API gives you, you might try to pause and reactivate the ad as soon as you launch it, so the API should collect that change of states. Please let me know if that was helpful!

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OMgVSixygi3v7Mu3hCAeTqat7kT30SW_?usp=sharing